# Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess

I have a folder somewhere on my webserver and a symlink to this folder from a public_html of another user. For the purpose of centralizing some content.

I can perfectly include files from within this symlinked folder.
However, I can not access a file (e.g. test.html or test.php) directly.

If I try to access a file directly I get a forbidden error in the browser and in the log files I see:

> Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible

I have tried to edit the httpconf as I found on the internet, tried to put a .htaccess in the folder where the symlink recides etc. But nothing has helped so far.

Additional info:
My webserver runs CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Apache 2.2.27

permissions to the parentfolder of the linked folder: 777

Permissions to the linked folder: 777

I have set them from 644 to 777 for testing purposes

And please note that I am a programmer running into problems, not a linux expert :)

*** I still do not have a working solution. I can use the files by including them, just fine, just not call any files directly e.g. images, stylesheets. I have no idea what other details to give that will help solve this problem.
The permissions are ok for the link, folder and parentfolder
Changing the owner of either link or folder does also not give any results
Options FollowSymLinks in .htaccess in the folder with the link, the parent of that folder, the destination folder and parent of destination folder, it does all not seem to help.
I can just not execute files and really need to

Comment: Take a look at the file system permissions of those folders.

Comment: sorry, not a programming question. Try SuperUser.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you, the permissions are drwxr-xr-x 5 on the target folder

Comment: I wonder why my question was downvoted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turned out that the symlink itself needed to be owned by the same user as the original linked folder

```
chown -R username: linkname
```

That did the trick for me

You can check the rights with

```
 ls -la
```

Then it looks a little wierd to see all the files owned by the actual user, except for the symlink, which is owned by the original user.

Hope this helps others with a similar issue as well!

Comment: I had to recreate the symbolic link, as I was not allowed to chown it

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the same problem I had.

Answer (score 6):

first of all I would recommend to include some details in your question. E.g. the permissions of dirs and files would be helpful, what distro etc.

My crystal ball analysis:
- You web-server (apache) runs as user www-data
- Your php runs a suexec user A / user b.
- The www-data user, cannot access the file, because the permission for www-data is not sufficient on the file or it's parent dir (!).

You could do:

```
$ sudo -u www-data ls -lah /path/to/your/file
```

... to see, what your webserver users sees.

```
$ ls -lah  /path/to/your/file
```

...  to check, what permissons are set to the file. (group/world readable?)

```
$ ls -dlah  /path/to/your
```

... to check the permissions on parent dir (need x flag for www-data),

HTH,
j.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I will update my question with the info. 
I have tried the commands that you supplied. The first one gives me the error: unknown user: www-data
The second command gives me -rwxrwxrwx 1 basesys basesys   21 Jun  2 13:46 test.php

Comment: Well. that means your web-server user is not called "www-data". Ubuntu/Debian calls that user "www-data". Depending on your distri, it might have a different name, e.g. www-run. Check with e.g. sudo cat /etc/passwd , if you cam spot the name ...

Answer (score 5):

In a `<Directory>` block in the Apache config, or in an `.htaccess` file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: I had also tried to put this in a .htaccess file, but this interfered with the rewrite rules and gave me this error in the log file:Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden

Comment: `Options FollowSymLinks` doesn't "interfere" with rewrite rules. Your error log is telling you something else is wrong with your config. You'll have to post more details.

Comment: Yes you are right, it was adding -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch that was advised elsewhere that had given that error. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: That's the solution for me